# Hide next <div> if previous <div> exists

Tags: jquery

What am i doing wrong?

```
$('function') {

$('#page #Description:has(.next('.subdescription'))').css('display', 'none');

});
```

where HTML is:

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="description"> </div>
  <div class="subdescription">Content</div>
</div>
```

Might be over thinking the solution?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? What is it doing instead?

Comment: I want to change the title to "Hide next <div> if previous <div> exists"; but I'm not sure if that's what the OP is trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) .next is a function not a selector.

2) Your run on onload usage of $('function') is incorrect.

3) The following should work

```
$(function(){
    if($('#page #description + .subdescription').length > 0){
        $('#page #description').hide();
    }
});
```

**Just going to add a bit of explanation below:**

```
$(function(){
```

This is equal to $(document).ready(function(){ /* code here */  })

```
$('#page #description + .subdescription')
```

Return all elements with class 'subdescription' that are siblings to the div with id of  'description'

```
$('#page #description').hide();
```

Shorthand for $('selector').css('display', 'none')